# Superset installing problem: ERROR:flask_appbuilder.security.sqla.manager:DB Creation and initialization failed

Tags: apache-superset

I have a problem with installing Superset. Locally everything works fine.
Loccaly i installed Superset (https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/superset/superset) with Rancher.
Now when installing on production Kubernetes cluster with the same configuration, errors occur. Pods:

```
dle-superset-549fb95f98-4zgzv           Running         
dle-superset-init-db-7nnnn              Error           
dle-superset-init-db-bvvjw              Error           
dle-superset-init-db-clr5h              Error           
dle-superset-init-db-fxg6s              Error           
dle-superset-init-db-ng7vs              Error           
dle-superset-init-db-qbf8g              Error           
dle-superset-init-db-zx6wl              Error           
dle-superset-postgresql-0               Running         
dle-superset-redis-master-0             Running         
dle-superset-worker-68ff776c6-56hnw     CrashLoopBackOff
```

Logs from `dle-superset-549fb95f98-4zgzv`

```
superset 2024-03-01 10:20:01,132:ERROR:flask_appbuilder.security.sqla.manager:DB Creation and initialization failed: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "dle-superset-postgresql" (10.105.247.235), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "superset"
superset 
superset (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
superset [2024-03-01 10:20:01 +0000] [3283] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 3283)
superset Loaded your LOCAL configuration at [/app/pythonpath/superset_config.py]
superset [2024-03-01 10:20:01 +0000] [12] [ERROR] Worker (pid:3283) exited with code 1
superset [2024-03-01 10:20:01 +0000] [12] [ERROR] Worker (pid:3283) exited with code 1.
superset [2024-03-01 10:20:01 +0000] [3313] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 3313
Stream closed EOF for alphada/dle-superset-549fb95f98-4zgzv (wait-for-postgres)
superset logging was configured successfully
superset 2024-03-01 10:20:04,258:INFO:superset.utils.logging_configurator:logging was configured successfully
superset 2024-03-01 10:20:04,265:INFO:root:Configured event logger of type <class 'superset.utils.log.DBEventLogger'>
superset /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_limiter/extension.py:293: UserWarning: Using the in-memory storage for tracking rate limits as no storage was explicitly specified. This is not recommended for production use. See: https://flask-limiter.readthedocs.io#configuring-a-storage-backend for documentation about configuring the storage backend.
superset   warnings.warn(
```

Changes I made to default values.yaml:

```
additionalRequirements:
  - sqlalchemy-trino

and

I set secret_key
```